# Website won't center on phone browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am wondering why my website [Miss Circle](http://www.misscircle.com/) is centered when viewed on my computer (Firefox, IE, Chrome) but left aligned when viewed on my smartphone (Chrome, Safari). The CSS layout was copied from my other website [Sneak Outfitters](http://www.sneakoutfitters.com/) which centers perfectly on my phone browsers. The only difference between the two websites is that one is 800px wide and one is 960px wide. I just can't understand why one is able to center while the other is left-aligned on phone browsers. I would appreciate any enlightenment on this issue,

Comment: You should show the HTML and/or CSS code here.

Comment: try `margin:auto` for divs inside